# Logarithmic Amplitude Spectral Subtraction

Tags: speech-processing, snr, mfcc, denoising, feature-extraction

I'm diving into audio processing and I'm trying to wrap my head around spectral subtraction. I learned there are different approaches do it based on power, magnitude, oversubtraction. My task is to perform the spectral subtraction based on the logarithmic amplitude.

My question here is:
What is the difference between magnitude spectral subtraction, logarithmic amplitude spectral subtraction, and oversubtraction?

My second question:
Which method would be more efficient for feature extraction in the context of irregular speech (noise, silence, mispronunciation...etc)

**Formulae**

Magnitude spectral subtraction: $\ |\hat{X}_m( \omega )| = max\{|Y_m( \omega )| -  E[|D_m( \omega )|],0\}$

Power spectral subtraction: $\ |\hat{X}_m( \omega )|^{2} =  max\{|Y_m( \omega )|^{2} -  E[|D_m( \omega )|^{2}],0\}$

Oversubtraction: $\ |\hat{X}_m( \omega )|^{2} =  max\{|Y_m( \omega )|^{2} -   \alpha E[|D_m( \omega )|^{2}], \beta[|D_m( \omega )|^{2}] \}$

Source [link](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~njb/teaching/sstutorial/part1.pdf)

I couldn't find the formula for the logarithmic amplitude spectral subtraction.

Thank you all and happy, and healthy new year.

Comment: Thank you for reformatting. Spectral subtraction has many aspects. Would you please add references, or how you understand formulae differ?

Comment: @LaurentDuval Thank you for your comment. I amended my post as you suggested.